# How to not run a function if it return an error because of dataset type

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following functions :

```
library("plyr")
library("doBy")
library("genefilter")
library("tidyverse")
    
    ballons=structure(list(YELLOW = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PURPLE", 
"YELLOW"), class = "factor"), SMALL = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("LARGE", "SMALL"), class = "factor"), STRETCH = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("DIP", "STRETCH"), class = "factor"), ADULT = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("ADULT", "CHILD"), class = "factor"), T = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))

char_dist_pairs<-function(x, y){
  
  i <- sapply(x, is.factor)
  x[i] <- lapply(x[i], as.character)
  j <- sapply(y, is.factor)
  y[j] <- lapply(y[j], as.character)
  i1 <- sapply(x, class)
  length_charachter_part <- length(which(i1 %in%
                                           c("factor", "character", "logical")))
  
  
  
  new <- as.numeric(table(unlist(x) == unlist(y))['TRUE'])
  
  
  m <- length_charachter_part - new
  
  
  m <- replace(m,is.na(m),0)
  
  return(m)
  
}



char_distance<-function(data){
  
  data= data %>% select_if(~!is.numeric(.))
  m=dist2(t(data),char_dist_pairs,diagonal = 0) 
  m=replace(m,is.na(m),0)
  return(m)
  
}

num_distance<-function(data){
  
  euclididan<-function(x,y){
  return(norm(na.omit(as.numeric(x-y)), type="2"))  
  }
  
  data= data %>% select(where(is.numeric))
  m=dist2(t(data),euclididan,diagonal = 0)
  m=replace(m,is.na(m),0)
  return(m)
  
}

similarite_matrice<-function(data){
  
return(num_distance(data)+char_distance(data))  
  
}
```

Those functions works as expected :

```
similarite_matrice(iris)
```

However with a **dataset with only categorical features** (like `ballons` dataset) , `similarite_matrice()` gives the following error :

```
similarite_matrice(ballons)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L) : a dimension is zero
```

Because the dataset is only categorical so we can't compute numerical distance :

```
num_distance(ballons)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L) : a dimension is zero
```

Here we are only able to compute distance between categorical features :

`char_distance(ballons)`

```
head(char_distance(ballons))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
[1,]    0    2    2    3    1    1    3    3    4     1     1     3     3     4     2     2     4     4     0
[2,]    2    0    2    1    3    3    1    3    2     3     3     1     3     2     4     4     2     4     3
[3,]    2    2    0    1    3    3    3    1    2     3     3     3     1     2     4     4     4     2     3
[4,]    3    1    1    0    4    4    2    2    1     4     4     2     2     1     0     0     3     3     2
[5,]    1    3    3    4    0    0    2    2    3     2     2     4     4     0     1     1     3     3     4
[6,]    1    3    3    4    0    0    2    2    3     2     2     4     4     0     1     1     3     3     4
```

We should also notice that :

```
ballons %>% select(where(is.numeric))
data frame with 0 columns and 19 rows
```

My question :

`similarite_matrice` is the sum of `num_distance` ( for numerical vectors) and `char_distance` ( for categorical features ). If the dataset contains only categorical features : I'm searching a way to avoid running `num_distance` because it will return an error !

I hope my question is clear !

Thank you in advance for help !

Comment: The posted data last column is not a factor, it's a logical column.

Comment: `could not find function "dist2"`. Is this function in package `genefilter`? If yes, then `package ‘genefilter’ is not available for this version of R`. (I'm running R 4.1.0).

Comment: yes it's from genefilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.
If no columns are numeric, compute the distance only for the other columns.

```
similarite_matrice <- function(data){
  i_num <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
  if(any(i_num))
    num_distance(data[i_num]) + char_distance(data)
  else
    char_distance(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an error, you could let your function return a warning.

```
similarite_matrice<-function(data){

if (ncol(data %>% select(where(is.numeric))==0) 
  return (warning("No numeric columns."))

return(num_distance(data)+char_distance(data))  
  
}
```

Comment: You need parenthesis around `return`'s argument.

Comment: He also needs a parenthesis around ncol(data %>% select(where(is.numeric))==0))

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution . It will works for all cases ( only categorical features , only numerical features , or mixed dataset with any features types ) :

```
similarite_matrice<-function(data){
  
  num_dist=matrix(0,nrow(data),nrow(data))
  
  char_dist=matrix(0,nrow(data),nrow(data))
  
  # we compute numerical distance if we have numerical columns 

  if (ncol(data %>% select(where(is.numeric)))!=0){
     num_dist=num_distance(data)
  } 
  
  # we compute categorical distance if we other data types ( factor , logical , etc )

  if(ncol(data %>% select_if(~!is.numeric(.)))!=0){
    
    char_dist=char_distance(data)
    
  }
  
  return(num_dist+char_dist)  
      
}
```